# How to Not change to initial state when other state change their value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Hello there I am phasing an logic issue where I don't want my other useState render(run) whenever another state change their value because it render full component every time so it initialize default values.
here when useEffect run and it change item value by setitem but after component run again so it initialize default again

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import {
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList,
  TextInput,
} from "react-native";

import { EvilIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons, Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import axios from "axios";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

import url from "../url";

const Handlenewspost = ({ navigation }) => {
  var items = navigation.getParam("item");
  var user = navigation.getParam("user");
  var functionforoffset = navigation.getParam("functionforoffset");
  const [item, setitem] = useState(items);

  var like = item.like;

  var found = like.find((element) => {
    if (element.username === user.username) return true;
  });
  found ? (item.userlike = true) : false;

  var checklike = "";
  item.userlike ? (checklike = "heart") : (checklike = "heart-outline");
  item.userlike ? (checkcolor = "red") : (checkcolor = "black");
  const [likebutton, setlikebutton] = useState(checklike);
 
  const [postlikes, setpostlikes] = useState(item.likes);
  const [likebuttoncolor, setlikebuttoncolor] = useState(checkcolor);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(url + "post/byid/" + items._id)
      .then((response) => {
        setitem(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(err.response.data.error);
        Alert.alert("Something went wrong", err.response.data.error, [
          { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") },
        ]);
      });
  }, []);

  const onpresshandle = async (item) => {
    userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userToken");
    id = item._id;
    token = userToken;
    functionforoffset();
    axios
      .post(url + "post/like", { token, id })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.data) {
        } else {
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(err.response.data.error);
        Alert.alert("Something went wrong", err.response.data.error, [
          { text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed") },
        ]);
      });
  };
  function checkcaption(caption) {
    if (caption != "") {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.safe}>
          <View
            style={[
              styles.root,
              { flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" },
            ]}
          >
            <Text style={[styles.textStyle, { fontSize: 15, marginLeft: 0 }]}>
              {item.caption}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    } else {
      return <View></View>;
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.card}>
            <View style={styles.cardheader}>
              {item.profileimage ? (
                <Image
                  source={{ uri: url + "filename/" + item.profileimage }}
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: 16,
                    marginRight: 8,
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    borderRadius: 100,
                  }}
                ></Image>
              ) : (
                <Image
                  source={require("../../assets/localbazilogo2.jpeg")}
                  style={[
                    styles.profileimage,
                    { marginLeft: 16, marginRight: 5 },
                  ]}
                ></Image>
              )}
              <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 15, marginLeft: 5 }}>
                {item.username}
              </Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.cardbody}>
              {item.filename ? (
                <Image
                  style={styles.cardbodyimage}
                  resizeMode="stretch"
                  source={{ uri: url + "filename/" + item.filename }}
                ></Image>
              ) : (
                <View></View>
              )}
            </View>
            <View style={styles.cardfooter}>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                onPress={() => {
                  if (item.userlike) {
                    setlikebutton("heart-outline");
                    setlikebuttoncolor("black");

                    setpostlikes(postlikes - 1);
                  } else {
                    setlikebutton("heart");
                    setlikebuttoncolor("red");

                    setpostlikes(postlikes + 1);
                  }

                  item.userlike = !item.userlike;

                  onpresshandle(item);
                }}
                name={likebutton}
                size={28}
                color={likebuttoncolor}
                style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginTop: 4 }}
              >
                {" "}
              </MaterialCommunityIcons>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 1 }}>{postlikes}</Text>
              <EvilIcons
                name="comment"
                size={30}
                style={{ marginLeft: 20, marginTop: 4 }}
                color="black"
              />
              <Image
                style={{ marginLeft: 20, marginTop: 4 }}
                source={require("../../assets/share.png")}
              ></Image>
            </View>
            {checkcaption(item.caption)}

            <View style={styles.showcomment}>
              <Text>
                View all {item.comments ? item.comments.length : 0} comments
              </Text>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.comment}>
              <View>
                {user.profileimage ? (
                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: url + "filename/" + user.profileimage }}
                    style={{
                      height: 35,
                      width: 35,
                      borderRadius: 100,
                      marginLeft: 14,
                    }}
                  ></Image>
                ) : (
                  <View></View>
                )}
              </View>

              <View style={styles.addcomment}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    marginHorizontal: 5,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    color: "#9CA3AF",
                    width: 240,
                  }}
                >
                  Add Comment
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

export default Handlenewspost;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  showcomment: { marginLeft: 20, marginBottom: 5 },
  addcomment: {
    overflow: "hidden",
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,

    padding: 7,
    backgroundColor: "#E6E7E9",
    borderRadius: 25,
  },
  comment: {
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  email: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    overflow: "hidden",
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 7,
    backgroundColor: "#E6E7E9",
    borderRadius: 25,
  },

  iconout: { width: "20%", alignItems: "center" },
  icon: { height: 35, width: 35, resizeMode: "stretch" },
  icons: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",

    marginTop: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 28,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  profileimage: {
    width: "12%",
    height: "170%",
    borderRadius: 100,
    resizeMode: "stretch",
  },
  safe: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: -10,
  },
  root: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 16,
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },

  container: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    flex: 1,
  },
  cardfooter: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  cardbodyimage: {
    height: 350,
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: 3,
    borderRadius: 3,
  },

  cardbody: {},
  cardheader: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginVertical: 12,
  },
  card: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    marginHorizontal: 4,
  },
});
```

Comment: The `useEffect` has an empty dependency array, it runs only once when the component mounts. If it's running more than this it means your component is being remounted for some reason. What is the "other state" that is being updated and causing the issue? I see also that you are mutating the `item` state in the `onPress` handler.

Comment: yes i understand but main problem is when useEffect change item state by setitem after that it re render component again so useState initialize default value again into item

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "so useState initialize default value again into item". `useState` only initializes state once, when the component mounts. Again... if this is occurring more than once, then it seems the component is being remounted. Any time you update state it will trigger a rerender.